# LAC (Lookahead Correction) corrects bison parser's error recovery into not working

Tags: c, parsing, error-handling, compiler-construction, bison

I have a bison parser and I got interested in the option `parse.lac full` because, according to the documentation, without it [the generated error message may be incorrect](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Reporting-Function.html).

However, when I add the option to my program, error recovery stops working correctly.

Here is an example:

```c
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex();
    void yyerror(const char *);
%}

%define parse.lac full
%define parse.error detailed

%%

prog:
      init statements { printf("program finished successfully!\n"); }
    ;

init:
      %empty
    | '!' '\n' { printf("an optional \"special\" first line\n"); }
    ;

statements:
      %empty
    | statements 'x' '\n' { printf("correct line\n"); }
    | statements error '\n' { yyerrok; printf("error line\n"); }
    ;

%%

int yylex()
{
    char c;
    if (scanf("%c", &c) != EOF)
        return c;
    else
        return YYEOF;
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main() {
    return yyparse();
}
```

For input (the bug occurs only when the input starts with an error):

```
illegal line
illegal line
```

it is supposed to return (output I get without LAC):

```
syntax error, unexpected invalid token, expecting end of file or 'x'
error line
syntax error, unexpected invalid token, expecting end of file or 'x'
error line
program finished successfully!
```

but when I turn LAC on, what I get instead is just:

```
syntax error, unexpected invalid token, expecting end of file or '!' or 'x'
```

So it indeed fixed the error message but the error recovery doesn't work anymore.

With debugging turned on it looks like this:

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Stack now 0
Reading a token
Next token is token invalid token ()
LAC: initial context established for invalid token
LAC: checking lookahead invalid token: Always Err
Constructing syntax error message
LAC: checking lookahead end of file: R2 G3 R4 G6 R1 G2 S5
LAC: checking lookahead '!': S1
LAC: checking lookahead '\n': R2 G3 R4 G6 Err
LAC: checking lookahead 'x': R2 G3 R4 G6 S8
syntax error, unexpected invalid token, expecting end of file or '!' or 'x'
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token invalid token ()
Stack now 0
```

I guess that maybe the parser's decision to use `Always Err` is the source of the problem? I don't know enough about how LAC works to really tell if this is true or what that means.

Is this a bug in LAC or in my program?
Can I fix it or LAC is just not viable for me?

---

I asked this [question](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bison/2023-03/msg00001.html) on the Bison's mailing list too but at time of writing this, there is no answer.