# Bison: Unexpected token error when trying to parse a multiline expression

Tags: c, parsing, bison, operator-precedence

I'm making a Visual Basic parser with Flex and Bison for a uni assignment. Most of it seems to be working properly except for the parsing of multiline expressions. Here is an example of a bit of code that doesn't work:

```
A = A +
1
```

And what is interesting is that removing `A =`  makes it parse properly. Same applies if I replace `=` with an operator with higher or equal precedence than that of `+`.

The parser seems to prioritize single line expressions over multiline ones. I understand that this is a precedence issue, but I have no idea how to solve this.

Truncated Flex code:

```
%option nounistd
%option noyywrap
%option case-insensitive

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parcer-mini.tab.h"

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define YY_DECL int yylex()

int result = 0;

%}
%x STRING_LITERAL

%%
%{
    char buf[100000];
    memset(buf, '\0', 100000);
%}

"+"                 { return '+'; }
"-"                 { return '-'; }
"*"                 { return '*'; }
"/"                 { return '/'; }
"="                 { return '='; }
"<"                 { return '<'; }
">"                 { return '>'; }
"^"                 { return '^'; }

([0-9]([0-9]+)?)  {yylval.int_val = atoi(yytext); return INT_VALUE;}

([a-zA-Z_])([a-zA-Z_0-9])* {yylval.id_var_name = (char *) malloc(strlen(yytext)+1); strcpy(yylval.id_var_name, yytext); return IDENTIFIER;}

\n+  {return END_OF_LINE;}

<<EOF>> { static int once = 0; return once++ ? 0 : END_OF_LINE;}
%%
```

Truncated Bison code:

```
%define parse.error verbose
%{
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int yylineno;
extern FILE* yyin;

extern int yyparse();
extern int yylex();

void yyerror(const char* s);
%}

%union {
    int int_val;
    char* id_var_name;
}

%type <expression> expr_singleline expr_multiline basic_literal_value;
%type <statement> stmt root;
%type stmt_ends;

%token<int_val> INT_VALUE

%token<id_var_name> IDENTIFIER

%token END_OF_LINE

%left '='
%left '>' '<'

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%right UNARY_MINUS UNARY_PLUS
%left '^'

%precedence IDENTIFIER

%start root

%%

root: stmt {printf("root 1\n");}
    ;
    
stmt: expr_multiline stmt_ends {printf("stmt 1\n");}
    | expr_singleline stmt_ends {printf("stmt 2\n");}
    ;          
    
stmt_ends: END_OF_LINE {printf("stmt_ends 1\n");}
    | stmt_ends END_OF_LINE {printf("stmt_ends 2\n");}
    ;
    
expr_singleline: basic_literal_value {printf("expr_single 0\n");}
    | '-' expr_singleline   %prec UNARY_MINUS {printf("expr_single 1\n");}
    | '+' expr_singleline   %prec UNARY_PLUS {printf("expr_single 2\n");}
    | expr_singleline '+' expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 3\n");}
    | expr_singleline '-' expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 4\n");}
    | expr_singleline '*' expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 5\n");}
    | expr_singleline '/' expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 6\n");}
    | expr_singleline '=' expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 8\n");}
    | expr_singleline '<' expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 9\n");}
    | expr_singleline '>' expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 10\n");}
    | expr_singleline '^' expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 11\n");}
    | IDENTIFIER {printf("expr_single 17\n");}
    ;

expr_multiline: expr_singleline '+' END_OF_LINE expr_singleline {printf("expr_multi 1\n");}
              | expr_singleline '-' END_OF_LINE expr_singleline {printf("expr_multi 2\n");}
              | expr_singleline '*' END_OF_LINE expr_singleline {printf("expr_multi 3\n");}
              | expr_singleline '/' END_OF_LINE expr_singleline {printf("expr_multi 4\n");}
              | expr_singleline '=' END_OF_LINE expr_singleline {printf("expr_multi 6\n");}
              | expr_singleline '<' END_OF_LINE expr_singleline {printf("expr_multi 7\n");}
              | expr_singleline '>' END_OF_LINE expr_singleline {printf("expr_multi 8\n");}
              | expr_singleline '^' END_OF_LINE expr_singleline {printf("expr_multi 9\n");}
              ;

basic_literal_value: INT_VALUE {printf("basic_literal_value int\n");}
                   ;                   
%%
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        yyparse();
    }
    else {
        yyerror("not found file");
    }
}

void yyerror(const char* s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", s);
    exit(1);    
}
```

Comment: Please paste a working example, preferably shorter. This doesn't compile for multiple reasons.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa Here is the repository: https://github.com/linkroot1/VBCompiler
To execute, go to the `lexer` folder and use the project there to run the parser. You can also make a node tree with `tree/draw_tree.bat`.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa As per your request, I have added truncated Flex and Bison code to the question. I tested it, and it's able to parse expressions just like the full version.

Comment: It's still really long but at least it works. You should try to make a [Minimal Reproducible Exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your chances of getting an answer. Not many people will be willing to go through all that code.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa Will this do?

Comment: Minimal means that you are not able to remove anything without making the problem no longer occur. Take this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75809021/3052438. I've removed the entire lexer and replaced it with one short function, and I left only 3 short rules. It took me a few hours to boil it down that much. This is useful not only to help readers of the question but also it often reveal the cause of the error. It's much easier to find when you have only a few lines and you know that all of them contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to solve the aforementioned issue, but I found a workaround. By creating an optional End of Line token, I merged expr_singleline and expr_multiline. This method works perfectly.

Modified truncated Bison code:

```
%define parse.error verbose
%{
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int yylineno;
extern FILE* yyin;

extern int yyparse();
extern int yylex();

void yyerror(const char* s);
%}

%union {
    int int_val;
    char* id_var_name;
}

%type <expression> expr basic_literal_value;
%type <statement> stmt root;
%type stmt_ends optEoL;

%token<int_val> INT_VALUE

%token<id_var_name> IDENTIFIER

%token END_OF_LINE

%left '='
%left '>' '<'

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%right UNARY_MINUS UNARY_PLUS
%left '^'

%precedence IDENTIFIER

%start root

%%

root: stmt {printf("root 1\n");}
    ;
    
stmt: expr stmt_ends {printf("stmt 2\n");}
    ;          
    
stmt_ends: END_OF_LINE {printf("stmt_ends 1\n");}
    | stmt_ends END_OF_LINE {printf("stmt_ends 2\n");}
    ;
    
optEoL: /*empty*/
      | END_OF_LINE {printf("optEoL 1\n");}
      ;
    
expr: basic_literal_value {printf("expr_single 0\n");}
    | '-' expr %prec UNARY_MINUS {printf("expr_single 1\n");}
    | '+' expr %prec UNARY_PLUS {printf("expr_single 2\n");}
    | expr '+' optEoL expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 3\n");}
    | expr '-' optEoL expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 4\n");}
    | expr '*' optEoL expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 5\n");}
    | expr '/' optEoL expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 6\n");}
    | expr '=' optEoL expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 8\n");}
    | expr '<' optEoL expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 9\n");}
    | expr '>' optEoL expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 10\n");}
    | expr '^' optEoL expr_singleline {printf("expr_single 11\n");}
    | IDENTIFIER {printf("expr_single 17\n");}
    ;

basic_literal_value: INT_VALUE {printf("basic_literal_value int\n");}
                   ;                   
%%
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        yyparse();
    }
    else {
        yyerror("not found file");
    }
}

void yyerror(const char* s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", s);
    exit(1);    
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I can't really tell why it makes a difference. Maybe some limitations to Bison lookahead but that's just a guess. Or maybe there just is some bug in the original version. You should run the parser in debug more and see what it does when it goes wrong.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa Maybe I should, but I really couldn't care less.